# Recording System Audio-Out + Built-in Mic While Using Earphones (Notability or other)

Tags: audio, microphone, recording

I've been using Notability to record meetings, as the recording is tied to notes, so finding specific information after the meeting is much easier; however, for online meetings (GoogleHangouts, FaceTime etc), I wear earphones so as to not disturb my coworkers.

**Does anyone know of any way I could set things up so that Notability records the signal going out to the earphones, as well as the input from the built-in mic?**

**Alternatively**, if **using earphones with a built-in mic** would offer a solution, I'd certainly be willing to invest.

This feature is *incredibly* helpful for staying organized, but I haven't been able to figure out a work-around for these online meetings (& > 50% of my meetings are online...).

Thanks in advance for your time & help!

Answer (score 1):

[Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/), from Rogue Amoeba, does a fantastic job with this. Perhaps a bit overkill for your needs, but it allows you to route audio channels to equalizers, to separate or combined files, etc. It's extremely powerful.

Given your use case though, I think [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) (which is free) may be just the ticket. Soundflower creates a virtual audio device that allows you to listen to your audio channel *and* use it as an input at the same time. (For example, you could record and listen to a radio broadcast at the same time).